# ANTLR does not automatically do lookahead matching?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

I'm currently writing a simple grammar that requires operator precedence and mixed associativities in one expression. An example expression would be `a -> b ?> C ?> D -> e`, which should be parsed as `(a -> (((b ?> C) ?> D) -> e)`. That is, the `?>` operator is a high-precedence left-associative operator wheras the `->` operator is a lower-precedence right-associative operator.

I'm prototyping the grammar in ANTLR 3.5.1 (via ANTLRWorks 1.5.2) and find that it can't handle the following grammar:

```
prog    :   expr EOF;
expr    :   term '->' expr
        |   term;
term    :   ID rest;
rest    :   '?>' ID rest
        |   ;
```

It produces `rule expr has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2` error.

The `term` and `rest` productions work fine in isolation when I tested it , so I assumed this happened because the parser is getting confused by `expr`. To get around that, I did the following refactor:

```
prog    :   expr EOF;
expr    :   term exprRest;
exprRest 
        :   '->' expr
        |   ;
term    :   ID rest;
rest    :   DU ID rest
        |   ;
```

This works fine. However, because of this refactor I now need to check for empty `exprRest` nodes in the output parse tree, which is non-ideal. Is there a way to make ANTLR work around the ambiguity in the initial declaration of `expr`? I would of assumed that the generated parser would fully match `term` and then do a lookahead search for `"->"` and either continue parsing or return the lone `term`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, the problem is in this rule:

```
expr    :   term '->' expr
        |   term;
```

The problematic part is the `term` which is common to both alternatives.

- **LL(1)** grammar doesn't allow this at all (unless `term` only matches zero tokens - but such rules would be pointless), because it cannot decide which alternative to use with only being able to see one token ahead (that's the *1* in *LL(1)*).
- **LL(k)** grammar would only allow this if the `term` rule could match at most `k - 1` tokens.
- **LL(*)** grammar which ANTLR 3.5 uses does some tricks that allows it to handle rules that match any number of tokens (ANTLR author calls this "variable look-ahead").

  - However, one thing that these tricks cannot handle is if the rule is recursive, i.e. if it or any rules it invokes reference itself in any way (direct or indirect) - and that is exactly what your `term` rule does:

    ```
    term    :   ID rest;
    rest    :   '?>' ID rest
            |   ;
    ```

    - the rule `rest`, referenced from `term`, recursively references itself. Thus, the error message

    > rule expr has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations ...

---

The way to solve this limitation of LL grammars is called left-factoring:

```
expr    :   term 
            ( '->' expr )?
        ;
```

What I did here is said "match term first" (since you want to match it in both alternatives, there's no point in deciding which one to match it in), then decide whether to match `'->' expr` (this can be decided just by looking at the very next token - if it's `->`, use it - so this is even *LL(1)* decision).

This is very similar to what you came to as well, but the parse tree should look very much like you intended with the original grammar.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation and helped me get over some conceptual barriers I was having with ANTLR, thanks alot for this. It will help with my latest project!

Comment: Also, it helps to know about the left-factoring trick because I found it tedious to have to walk an `expRest` node to check if it was empty or not. Thanks again